# Yii2 query of search model inside foreach loop

Tags: php, yii2

This is my code but it outputs only last user inserted. I mean that it do not display others users registered to a particular business. The user should only see the users that are registered with his business. Thanks in advance

I am using `yii2` advanced.

I have 3 tables

- First table - user_tbl (user.id, user.username, user.email)
- Second table - userinfo_tbl(info.id, info.userid, info.business id)
- Third table - Business_tbl(business.id, business.name)

  ```
   public function search($params)
      {
       //current user logedin
           $CurrentUserID = Yii::$app->user->getId();

      //Find business to which current user is registered
           $BusinessID = Yii::$app->mycomponent->getBusinessID($CurrentUserID);

      //Now find all the users with this business id
          $BusinessUsers=  Yii::$app->mycomponent->getBusinessUsersID($BusinessID);

           foreach ($BusinessUsers as $BusinessUser)
               {
               $UID=$BusinessUser['user_id'];

               }

          $query = User:: find()->where(['id'=>$UID]); 

          $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
              'query' => $query,
              'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['id'=>SORT_ASC]],
              'pagination' => [
                  'pageSize' => $this->_pageSize,
              ]
          ]);
  ```

Comment: Please show us `getBusinessUsersID` method code. Inside the foreach you are assigning `$UID=` each time and overwriting last value. As it stands this code makes no sense at all.

Comment: `$UID[] = $BusinessUser['user_id'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code = $UID should be an array, otherwise it will always have a single id. the last in your $businessUsers. 
change your code to this:

```
    public function search($params)
{
 //current user logedin
     $CurrentUserID = Yii::$app->user->getId();

//Find business to which current user is registered
     $BusinessID = Yii::$app->mycomponent->getBusinessID($CurrentUserID);

//Now find all the users with this business id
    $BusinessUsers=  Yii::$app->mycomponent->getBusinessUsersID($BusinessID);

    //check if $BusinessUsers has records...
    $UID = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn($BusinessUsers, 'user_id');
    $query = User:: find()->where(['in','id', $UID]); 
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['id'=>SORT_ASC]],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => $this->_pageSize,
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way

```
public function search($params)
{
    //current user logedin
    $CurrentUserID = Yii::$app->user->getId();

    //Find business to which current user is registered
    $BusinessID = Yii::$app->mycomponent->getBusinessID($CurrentUserID);

    //Now find all the users with this business id
    $BusinessUsers=  Yii::$app->mycomponent->getBusinessUsersID($BusinessID);
    $UID = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($BusinessUsers,'user_id','user_id');

    $query = User:: find()->where(['id'=>$UID]); 
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['id'=>SORT_ASC]],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => $this->_pageSize,
        ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put all the ID's in a comma delimited list then use an `IN` query in your where condition.

```
public function search($params)
    {
     //current user logedin
         $CurrentUserID = Yii::$app->user->getId();

    //Find business to which current user is registered
         $BusinessID = Yii::$app->mycomponent->getBusinessID($CurrentUserID);

    //Now find all the users with this business id
        $BusinessUsers=  Yii::$app->mycomponent->getBusinessUsersID($BusinessID);

         foreach ($BusinessUsers as $BusinessUser)
             {
             array_push($UID,$BusinessUser['user_id']); //put all IDs in an array
             }
        $UID = implode(',',$UID); //making it look like this 1,2,3,4
        $query = User:: find()->where('id IN ('.$UID.')'); 

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['id'=>SORT_ASC]],
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => $this->_pageSize,
            ]
        ]);
```